# Saving SQL Lab query as dataset?

Tags: apache-superset

currently, to create a virtual dataset in superset, I create a dataset based on a physical table and edit it afterwards. This feels not as straight forward as I expected, so perhaps there is a better way to do this? I especially expected a way to create a dataset from a SQL Lab query.

Am I missing an option to do so?

Thx,
Holger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. A virtual dataset in Superset is more / less really just a query (albeit with some optional additions, like jinja templated variables).

- **SQL Lab to virtual dataset**: When you're in SQL Lab, any query you run can be published as a virtual dataset by clicking "Explore". You'll be then asked to give a name to the virtual dataset and a no-code Explore workflow will be kicked off with this virtual dataset as the data context / input!
- **Editing existing virtual dataset**: To edit the virtual Dataset (which again is mostly a SQL query), you select Edit from the Datasets tab next to the line item for your dataset.

I think the first bullet is what you're looking for :)

The following documentation may also be helpful: https://docs.preset.io/docs/sql-editor#results-tab

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Srini. After running the query, the results tab shows the explore button which allows saving it as virtual dataset. And thanks for the pointer to te docs as well.

Answer (score 0):

. "Save" just saves as query, not as dataset.

1. create sql
2. type "explore"
3. save as virtual dataset

Answer (score -1):

I don't have superset open right now, but yes, you can run a query in SQL Lab and then save it as a virtual dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still don't find the option to do so. "Save" just saves as query, not as dataset.